# is it possible to send multiple forms to php self with post

Tags: php

I have only been able to do this with GET, How do I submit multiple forms without the previous data being lost when resubmitting  a different form via POST ?

Answer (score 5):

Use hidden input fields?

```
<input type="hidden" />
```

Store in a session?

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['blarr'] = $_POST['old-data'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Persist the previous form data into a database or session.

Answer (score 3):

Take your previous data in session array.

Or you can post your data again using hidden fields in your form.

Answer (score -1):

This code should loop through all POST and insert them into a hidden input field. Put it inside the `<form>` tags, and it should be submitted with the subsequent post.

**Remember to properly escape the output.**

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value){
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
}
```

Or you can save away the data in the manner you choose.